# Clean SQL: Should I reference dates that I could ask for in my database?

Tags: sql, sqlite, date, indexing, query-optimization

I have millions of rows in my database SQLite Studio.
I would like to ask it which months I can have.
When I do my request, it takes a long time (5 min, more than the half of time that it took to get my data for a month!)

```
--How I call for months BTW -- 
SELECT DISTINCT strftime('%Y-%m', time_UTC) AS month FROM transacts ORDER BY month ASC;
```

It could be really fast if I create a table with all available months but I hear a little voice in my head telling:

> YOU HAVE NOT TO MAKE A DATE TABLE

But I don't remember if it's bad and why. It sound to me pretty well.
What do you think about please?

EDIT :
How to speed up a request SQL on dates available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an index on the expression `strftime('%Y-%m', time_UTC)` to get better performance:

```
CREATE INDEX id_transacts_time ON transacts(strftime('%Y-%m', time_UTC));
```

Check in the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=13636330bc4a26016be84b92e4198116) the query plan that uses the index.

Comment: @Nicoolasens you don't change anything. The code in my answer creates an index not on the column `time_UTC` but on the expression `strftime('%Y-%m', time_UTC)`.

Comment: Thx for this fast aswer. 
Is this command will ALTER my table ?

Comment: @Nicoolasens no, the table is not altered.

Comment: Ok, it works very well. My request took 10 sec instead of 5 min !
Thanks a lot forpas !